# displaying reporting weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting

I dont know how to loop through so that the query displays all the weeks from the reporting date?

The code determines the Mon - Sun week then should insert the values in a temp table to then query the weeks. I have hard coded the report_date and its hould display more than one record.

any ideas

```
DECLARE @REPORT_DATE DATETIME, @WEEK_BEGINING VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @REPORT_DATE = '2011-01-01T00:00:00'
--SELECT @REPORT_DATE = GETDATE() -- should grab the date now.
SELECT @WEEK_BEGINING = 'MONDAY'
IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'MONDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 1
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'TUESDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 2
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'WEDNESDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 3
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'THURSDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 4
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'FRIDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 5
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'SATURDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 6
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'SUNDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 7
DECLARE @WEEK_START_DATE DATETIME, @WEEK_END_DATE DATETIME
--GET THE WEEK START DATE
SELECT @WEEK_START_DATE = @REPORT_DATE - (DATEPART(DW, @REPORT_DATE) - 1)
--GET THE WEEK END DATE
SELECT @WEEK_END_DATE = @REPORT_DATE + (7 - DATEPART(DW, @REPORT_DATE))
PRINT 'Week Start: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @WEEK_START_DATE)
PRINT 'Week End: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @WEEK_END_DATE)

CREATE TABLE #WeekList
    (
    month_date date
    )


DECLARE @Interval int = 1

INSERT INTO #WeekList SELECT @WEEK_START_DATE

WHILE @Interval < 1
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #WeekList SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, - @Interval, @WEEK_START_DATE)
    SET @Interval = @Interval + 1
    END

SELECT  
--Create the month ID code:     

@WEEK_START_DATE AS Start_Week, @WEEK_END_DATE AS End_Week


FROM #WeekList
ORDER BY Start_Week DESC

DROP TABLE #WeekList
```

Comment: Could you please give some example data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DATEADD and updating your @interval initialization and updated loop logic:

```
DECLARE @REPORT_DATE DATETIME, @WEEK_BEGINING VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @REPORT_DATE = '2011-01-01T00:00:00'
--SELECT @REPORT_DATE = GETDATE() -- should grab the date now.
SELECT @WEEK_BEGINING = 'MONDAY'
IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'MONDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 1
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'TUESDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 2
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'WEDNESDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 3
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'THURSDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 4
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'FRIDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 5
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'SATURDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 6
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'SUNDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 7
DECLARE @WEEK_START_DATE DATETIME, @WEEK_END_DATE DATETIME
--GET THE WEEK START DATE
SELECT @WEEK_START_DATE = @REPORT_DATE - (DATEPART(DW, @REPORT_DATE) - 1)
--GET THE WEEK END DATE
SELECT @WEEK_END_DATE = @REPORT_DATE + (7 - DATEPART(DW, @REPORT_DATE))
PRINT 'Week Start: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @WEEK_START_DATE)
PRINT 'Week End: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @WEEK_END_DATE)

DECLARE @Interval int = datediff(WEEK,getdate(),@WEEK_START_DATE)+1

SELECT Start_Week=@WEEK_START_DATE
, End_Week=@WEEK_END_DATE
INTO #WeekList

WHILE @Interval <= 0
    BEGIN
    set @WEEK_START_DATE=DATEADD(WEEK,1,@WEEK_START_DATE)
    set @WEEK_END_DATE=DATEADD(WEEK,1,@WEEK_END_DATE)
    INSERT INTO #WeekList values (@WEEK_START_DATE,@WEEK_END_DATE)
    SET @Interval += 1;
    END

SELECT *
FROM #WeekList
ORDER BY Start_Week DESC

DROP TABLE #WeekList
```

Results (top 5 and bottom 5 of list):

```
Start_Week              End_Week
----------------------- -----------------------
2012-03-12 00:00:00.000 2012-03-18 00:00:00.000
2012-03-05 00:00:00.000 2012-03-11 00:00:00.000
2012-02-27 00:00:00.000 2012-03-04 00:00:00.000
2012-02-20 00:00:00.000 2012-02-26 00:00:00.000
2012-02-13 00:00:00.000 2012-02-19 00:00:00.000
...
2011-01-24 00:00:00.000 2011-01-30 00:00:00.000
2011-01-17 00:00:00.000 2011-01-23 00:00:00.000
2011-01-10 00:00:00.000 2011-01-16 00:00:00.000
2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 2011-01-09 00:00:00.000
2010-12-27 00:00:00.000 2011-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

As an aside, you could also use the `date` type instead of `Datetime`, if you don't need to store the time.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect... is there a way to display this :2012-03-19 00:00:00.000 as "19-Mon-2012" ?

Comment: You bet. If you mean "19-_Mar_-2012", you can use `CONVERT` with formatting, like `REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(30),getdate(),106),' ','-')`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to list the weeks and the corresponding counts or sums, you can do this as follows

**Sample data**

```
myDate
----------
2012-03-15
2012-03-15
2012-03-15
2012-03-14
2012-03-14
2012-03-14
2012-03-14
2012-03-09
2012-03-09
2012-03-09
2012-03-08
2012-03-08
2012-03-08
2012-03-01
2012-03-01
2012-03-01
2012-03-01
2012-02-29
2012-02-29
2012-02-29
2012-02-29
2012-02-23
2012-02-23
2012-02-23
2012-02-22
2012-02-22
2012-02-22
2012-02-22
```

**Script for sample data**

```
create table #myTable(mydate Date)

insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -1, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -1, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -1, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -2, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -2, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -2, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -2, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -8, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -8, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -8, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -15, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -15, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -15, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -15, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -16, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -16, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -16, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -16, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -22, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -22, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -22, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -23, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -23, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -23, getdate())
insert into #myTable select DATEADD(day, -23, getdate())
```

**Expected Result**

```
Count   WeekStart   WeekEnd
-----   ----------  ----------
7       2012-02-20  2012-02-24
8       2012-02-27  2012-03-02
6       2012-03-05  2012-03-09
7       2012-03-12  2012-03-16
```

**How to do**

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

SELECT
    COUNT(*) [Count],
    DATEADD(DD, -(DATEPART(DW, mydate)-1), mydate) [WeekStart],
    DATEADD(DD, 7-(DATEPART(DW, mydate)+2), mydate) [WeekEnd]
FROM
    #myTable
WHERE 
    DATEPART(dw, mydate) >= 1 AND DATEPART(dw, mydate) <= 5 -- only weekdays
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(DD, -(DATEPART(DW, mydate)-1), mydate),
    DATEADD(DD, 7-(DATEPART(DW, mydate)+2), mydate)
ORDER BY
    DATEADD(DD, -(DATEPART(DW, mydate)-1), mydate)
```